# How to get the last index in a JSON array when you don't know how large the array is going to be?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, for-loop

I have an array of JSON objects. This array is within a for loop and it keeps adding them to the array as the information becomes available from the database. The number of the objects in the array might not be the same as the number of results returned from the database (because only some locations might have the type of food a user is searching for).

For instance, I can have 12 restaurants returned in `rows`, however only 3 sell hamburgers, so I can't simply do `if (rows.length - 1 == i)`, because `i` is only going to reach 2 while `rows.length - 1` is 11.

So the matching returned results (JSON) are added one by one in a for loop. I can never preemptively know how many restaurants sell burgers until all those restaurants that do are added to the array.

I've tried a variety of tricks and the usual error I get from node is "can't send headers more than once." And I know why it's giving me this error. It's giving me this error because every iteration of the loop it will return whatever it has in the array.

An example of output

First iteration:

`{ "results": [ {"name_of_restaurant": "joes burgers", "open_now": true }] }`

Second iteration:

`{ "results": [ {"name_of_restaurant": "joes burgers", "open_now": true }, { "name_of_restaurant": "five guys", "open_now": true }] }`

Third iteration:

`{ "results": [ { "name_of_restaurant": "joes burgers", "open_now": true }, "{ name_of_restaurant": "five guys", "open_now": true }, 
" { name_of_restaurant": "shake shack", "open_now": true }] 
 }`

I want a way to capture the third iteration so I can send that back to the client.

To be clear, I am not looking for `array.length - 1`. My problem is substantially more complex.

**EDIT - code added**

```
function retrieveLocation(callback) {
    var locationsWithinVisibleMapRectQuery = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE Y(coordinates) > " + req.body.SWCoordLat + "AND Y(coordinates) < " + req.body.NECoordLat + "AND X(coordinates) > " + req.body.SWCoordLong + "AND X(coordinates) < " + req.body.NECoordLong + ";";
    connection.query(locationsWithinVisibleMapRectQuery, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err; 

        var jsonObject = {
            "results" : []
        };

        //console.log("Number of businesses: " + rows.length);

        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

            console.log("Business number " + i); 
            var businessName = rows[i].name;
            console.log(businessName);
            console.log();
            var x = rows[i].coordinates.x; 
            var y = rows[i].coordinates.y; 

            getMenuForEachLocation(x, y, businessName, rows, i, function(err, obj) {

                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null); 
                }  

                jsonObject["results"].push(obj);

                if( jsonObject["results"] == the last index) { // figure a way to get last iteration to send back as a response
                     callback(null, jsonObject);  
                 }
            }); 
        }
    }); 
}

retrieveLocation(function(err, jsonObject) {
    if (err) throw err; 

    res.json(jsonObject);
});
```

Comment: Why are you returning results before the containing for loop is finished iterating? Can we see the code that builds this array?

Comment: _"I want a way to capture the third iteration"_ Is requirement to only perform a process at third iteration ?

Comment: I posted my code for you to see.

Comment: Is `getCheckinsForEachLocation` asynchronous ?

Comment: Is using promises not an option for you? Would really help out here for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @guest271314, I want a way to capture the last iteration. Just in this case it happened to be the third iteration for example's sake. The complete result won't get the completely calculated results until the very last iteration.

Comment: @gabdallah, unfortunately I don't know what promises are. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Have you tried using `if (i === rows.length)` ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, I've used `if (i === rows.length - 1)` and it is asynchronous.

Comment: What was result using `if (i === rows.length - 1)` ?

Comment: @Mihado you can learn more here: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html and they are part of the es6 spec (but I still recommend bluebird). Essentially, as opposed to giving an async function a callback, you wrap it in a promise - which will allow you to continue on as if you had a value, and will resolve once it errors out or returns something. In this case, you could easily iterate over the rows using map, returning out the second async call - and after that is done executing, just grab the last index as normal.

Comment: @guest271314 the output that I placed above.

Comment: Can I suppose you used `if (i === rows.length - 1)` inside `getCheckinsForEachLocation()` function?

Comment: Yes, I've even tried that. But that function is unrelated because it returns a singleton object for a specific location which I later add to the `jsonObject["results"]` array in the for loop.

Comment: Are you expecting `jsonObject.results` to be in same order as `rows` , or corresponding to `i` ?

Comment: @guest271314 well I suppose I am, but that's irrelevant. My ultimate issue is that I might have 12 restaurants in a visible map, but only 3 sell burgers. Each iteration I add a restaurant that sells burgers, but I want to wait till the very last place that sells burgers to be added to the array before I send back the results.

Comment: @Mihado See post; `callback` will not be called until `results` `.length` is equal to `rows` `.length` . You could use `Array.prototype.sort()` to sort the `results` array to match `rows` array ; or sort the `results` array in-place by assigning `i` as index of `results` to place returned data

Comment: In your case the callback will never be called because results.length in my example will be 3 while rows.length will be 12, thus giving me no response. Am I right in that assumption. What i'm trying to say is that results.length might not reach rows.length, so I can't dependent on using rows.length.

Comment: _"I want a way to capture the last iteration."_ Is requirement for `callback` to be invoked at third response received, whether that response is `i:10` or `i:12` ? Or at precisely index `3` of `rows` iteration ?

Comment: @guest271314, I will try to implement your method and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @guest271314 index 3 is just an arbitrary index that I picked for my example. It could be index 500, I just need to be able to get the last iteration. In my example rows.length represents the number of businesses on the map that are restaurants. While the results array is the number of places that sell burgers.

Comment: How do you determine how many places that sell burgers ? Is this number a variable ?

Comment: I make a call to an API that tells me if that's an item they have on their menu. I get the number of restaurants on my visible map (which is rows). Then I create an obj which I return to store in my results array for each business that sells burgers.

Comment: Then you should have a variable that represents the total number of places that sell burgers ? And you can query the response to determine if the response is a place that sells burgers ?

Comment: There's no variable that tells you exactly how many places sell burgers. The map is changing and the only thing that this api tells me is whether burgers is on their menu (true), or not (false).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104691/discussion-between-guest271314-and-mihado).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An working example of an approach that checks for `.length` of `results` array to be equal to `.length` of `rows` array. Note, since `results` is filled asynchronously, the resulting array may not be in order of `i`

```js
var rows = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  
, results = []

, asyncFn = function(n) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(n)
    }, Math.random() * 3000)
  })
}

, complete = function(callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    asyncFn(i).then(function(data) {
      results.push(data);
      console.log(results);
      if (results.length === rows.length) callback(rows, results)
    })
  }
}

complete(
  // `callback` : do stuff when `results` `.length` is equal to `rows` `.length`
  function(rows_, results_) {
    console.log(rows_, results_)
    alert("complete");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the callback function of `getCheckinsForEachLocation()` only fire if the condition is met, so there is no way you can know when all the data is processed inside the callback function.

We currently know how many rows are with `rows.length`, and what we need to know is when all the `getCheckinsForEachLocation()` fired, so we need another index and a `oncomplete` callback.

This is a working example:

```js
var globalIndex;

// Pseudo async function
function getCheckinsForEachLocation (rows, i, callback, oncomplete) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (-1 != rows[i].indexOf('burgers')) {
      callback(null, rows[i]);
    }

    // Add up the times that the function was called to
    // find out if they have called all.
    if (++globalIndex == rows.length) {
      oncomplete();
    }
  }, Math.random() * 3000);
}

function retrieveLocation(callback) {
  // Pseudo data retrived from database
  var rows = ["sandwich", "burgers 1", "salad", "burgers 2", "sushi", "burgers 3", "tea"];

  var jsonObject = {
    "results" : []
  };

  // Reset the time that `getCheckinsForEachLocation` was called
  globalIndex = 0;

  for (var i = 0, rowsLength = rows.length; i < rowsLength; ++i) {
    console.log("Business number " + i);
    getCheckinsForEachLocation(rows, i, function(err, obj) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
      }

      jsonObject["results"].push(obj);
    }, function () {
      callback(null, jsonObject);
    });
  }
}

retrieveLocation(function(err, jsonObject) {
    if (err) throw err;

    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned promises earlier - this may work for your needs. I definitely recommend checking out more about promises. Quick note, this is all es6 - so don't get too tied up w/ the arrow function syntax etc. If you're running node 4.0 >= then this should work out of the box;

```
function retrieveLocation() {
    const locationsWithinVisibleMapRectQuery = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE Y(coordinates) > " + req.body.SWCoordLat + "AND Y(coordinates) < " + req.body.NECoordLat + "AND X(coordinates) > " + req.body.SWCoordLong + "AND X(coordinates) < " + req.body.NECoordLong + ";";
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query(locationsWithinVisibleMapRectQuery, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(rows);
      });
    })
    .then(rows => {
      return Promise.all(rows.map(row => {
        const businessName = row.name;
        const x = row.coordinates.x; 
        const y = row.coordinates.y; 
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          getCheckinsForEachLocation(x, y, businessName, rows, i, (err, result) => {
            if (err) reject (err);
            resolve(result);
          })
        })
        .then(result => result)
        .catch(err => {
          throw new Error(err)
        }); 
      }));
    })
    .then(result => result[result.length - 1]); 
}

retrieveLocation()
  .then(jsonObject => res.json(jsonObject))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```