# how to call only last promise from loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript, promise

I am new in promises,can any body help
here promise is resolving randomly,how to resolve last promise from loop when full loop execute
here suppose this.selectedValues has 4 values but some time it update only three and some time it update all values(4), this is problem from promise

```
var promise;
private values: Object[] = [];
_.each(this.selectedValues, (selectedValue) => {
    promise = that.valueService.getValuesForName(selectedValue).then((pg) => {
        values.push({
            Id: pg.Id,
            Name: pg.Name,
            Description: pg.Description,
            Policies: pg.Policies
        });
    });
});

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.then(() => { // i want to call promise only once for last index
        var data: Object = {
            Id: that.id,
            Name: name,
            Description: description,
            Values: values
        };
        that.updateEdit(data, name);
    });
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664216/how-to-get-the-last-index-in-a-json-array-when-you-dont-know-how-large-the-arra

Comment: Look at the $q service's all() method. It takes an array or hash of promises and returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises have resolved. If any of the promises rejects, $q.all() rejects immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
var promise = Promise.resolve();
private values: Object[] = [];
_.each(this.selectedValues, (selectedValue) => {
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        return that.valueService.getValuesForName(selectedValue);
    }).then((pg) => {
        values.push({
            Id: pg.Id,
            Name: pg.Name,
            Description: pg.Description,
            Policies: pg.Policies
        });
    });
});

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.then(() => { // i want to call promise only once for last index
        var data: Object = {
            Id: that.id,
            Name: name,
            Description: description,
            Values: values
        };
        that.updateEdit(data, name);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thanks a lot for replying finally $q solved my problem

 var promise,promises=[];
private values: Object[] = [];
_.each(this.selectedValues, (selectedValue) => {
    promise = that.valueService.getValuesForName(selectedValue).then((pg) => {
        values.push({
            Id: pg.Id,
            Name: pg.Name,
            Description: pg.Description,
            Policies: pg.Policies
        });
    });
      promises.push(promise);
});

 var combinedPromise = this.$q.all(promises);
if (combinedPromise !== undefined) {
    combinedPromise.then(() => { // i want to call promise only once for last index
        var data: Object = {
            Id: that.id,
            Name: name,
            Description: description,
            Values: values
        };
        that.updateEdit(data, name);
    });
```